# How to get the node level of the selected node of a treeview in a widow based wpf appliction?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, data-binding, wpf-controls

Im developing a window based application using wpf. i have a window with a treeview and frame in it. i want to control the data populating in the frame using the treveview nodes. Just like our file explorer in our windows machines. for that i need to know what is the level of the node i have selected on the treeview. I know how to do this with window forms but im new to WPF. Please some one kindly help me how to get the nodelevel of treeview in WPF.

Note: im populating the treeview from a backend table programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the level of a treeview in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437840/the-level-of-a-treeview-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

As @Jobi said in the following link : [the level of a treeview in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437840/the-level-of-a-treeview-in-wpf)

*The direct answer to your question is that there is no level property in WPF.
There is no one to one relationship between the winforms controls and wpf control. Because the underlying architecture and usage is totally different in both. In WPF you will bind a heirarchical data(LinkedList kind of Datastructure) to a TreeView and define a HeirarchicalDataTemplate to the Treeview.ItemTemplate property*

I hope this will help you.

Comment: The code that was available in the link was in C#, i need something similar to that in VB